# mysql - The target table of the UPDATE is not updatable

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql query:

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT * FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B 
ON table_A.id=table_B.a_fk 
WHERE table_A.batch=10) AS TBL_1 
SET TBL_1.b_name = "test" WHERE TBL_1.a_fk = 67532;
```

When i run it, i get the following error message:

```
The target table TBL_1 of the UPDATE is not updatable.
```

I need to update the column 'b_name' in table_B where the batch value is 10 in table_A.

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: when you run only this part `SELECT * FROM table_A ...` what do u get

Comment: At first sight, shouldn't you say "SET table_B.b_name = "test"" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table_B b 
set b.b_name = 'test'
where b.a_fk in 
(
select id from table_A where batch=10
)
```