# Error getting with the target table of the UPDATE is not updatable

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am running a simple MySQL query to update with sub-query . This is the query what i wrote

```
UPDATE (
         SELECT IP2.ID, IP2.IP4, IP2.CLIENT FROM IP_ADDRESS IP2 WHERE IP2.V_NET = VNET_ID AND IP2.CLIENT IS NULL AND IP2.IP4 < (RANG_E - 1) 
         ORDER BY IP2.IP4, IP2.CLIENT LIMIT 1
         )AS IP SET IP.CLIENT = C_ID;
```

after running i am getting following error :

```
The target table IP2 of the UPDATE is not updatable
```

I have got some related question [mysql - The target table of the UPDATE is not updatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228740/mysql-the-target-table-of-the-update-is-not-updatable)
and 
[The target table of the UPDATE is not updatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498468/the-target-table-of-the-update-is-not-updatable) but i didn't get a clear answer .

Anything i am missing here ? how can i write this query ? Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have primary key on your table you are safe.

Take a look to this dirty trip:

[Try it at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0df95/1)

**sample table**:

```
create table t( a char(1), i int );

insert into t values 
('a', 1),
('b', 2),
('c', 3),
('d', 4);
```

**Updating through pk**

```
/* updating using double subquery, only way to use your same table */

update t
set a = 'z'
where i = (select i from (select * from t) t2  order by i desc limit 1);
```

Apply it tou your environment.

Answer (score 1):

The format of an UPDATE statement is as follows:

```
UPDATE [table name]
   SET [column name] = [new value]
(optional WHERE clauses)
```

The update sql you wrote in your question makes no sense. Rewrite it using the correct structure.